# FSEventStream Changing the paths to watch dynamically

Tags: objective-c, fsevents

I need to monitor a large list of files for deletion or movement. And this list can change dynamically quite a number of times. Is it possible to change the paths to watch of the `FSEventStreamContext` while the monitoring is in progress?

Is there any other better way to achieve this instead of using `FSEvents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [GCD dispatch sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_source_create) to observe filesystem events.
An advantage over the (older) FSEvents API is, that dispatch sources notify via block-based handlers.

You can also specify a mask for the events that you are interested in (e.g. `DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE`|`DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME` for renames and deletions)

```
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop/test.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
    dispatch_queue_t observerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("filesystem-observer-queue", 0);
    int fileDescriptor = open([url fileSystemRepresentation], O_EVTONLY);
    dispatch_source_vnode_flags_t eventMask = DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE|DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME;
    dispatch_source_t fileSystemSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE, fileDescriptor, eventMask, observerQueue);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(fileSystemSource, ^{
        dispatch_source_vnode_flags_t eventSourceFlag = dispatch_source_get_data(fileSystemSource);
        if(eventSourceFlag & DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE)
        {
            NSLog(@"delete");
            dispatch_source_cancel(fileSystemSource);
        }
        else if(eventSourceFlag & DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME)
        {
             NSLog(@"rename");
        }
        NSLog(@"Change at %@ of type %lu", url, eventSourceFlag);
    });
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(fileSystemSource, ^{
        close(fileDescriptor);
    });
    dispatch_resume(fileSystemSource);
```

Some notes:

- The above code just shows the general idea. It does not try to cover all edge cases.
- When you observe a directory, you only get one notification that *something* changed, but no information about the affected file(s) or the change type.
- DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE means true deletion (e.g. not the Finders move to trash)

Comment: I might have to monitor around 500 files located in different locations.. is it possible via a single source? and also as i mentioned in the question, if it is possible by a single source, is it possible to change the list of files while the monitoring is in progress?

Comment: No. If the files to observe don't share a common parent directory, you'd need dedicated sources for each file. I don't know if there is a hard limit for dispatch sources or if it is advisable to use them for >500 files. You'll need to research/experiment :)

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me I have made a file in my desktop called `test.txt`, put your code in a function, called onviewdidload, and deleted `test.txt` but no `NSLog(@"delete");` is being called?!